# Dynamic Bootstrap dropdown not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two Bootstrap 3.0 dropdowns, one for book and one for chapter (for reference, the site I'm working on is http://www.jbtbible.com/mobile). The html for both dropdowns is in a single file (I have them set up as a btn-group) with the book list being hard coded and the chapter list being populated dynamically using jquery after the buttons load. I use jquery to register selection and manage books/chapters from there. This works fine on all desktop browsers I have tried, and the book selection works on mobile browsers, but the chapter selection does not work on mobile browsers (it builds the list, but selecting an option does nothing). I can't figure out what the difference would be because the generated code looks exactly the same between the two, and selection is registered the same for both.

Here are some of the relevant pieces of code:

In my header I have this as a placeholder for the dropdown buttons:

```
<div class="book-btn-fill">   
</div>
```

This is filled in by this jquery function:

```
var bookList = ["JBTHome", "Galatians","Ephesians","Philippians", "Philemon"];
var chapterList = [1,6,6,2,1];

function loadText() {
    $(".book-btn-fill").load('../book-selection-dropdown.html', function() {
        $(".book-button").html('<b>' + bookList[curBook] + '</b>');
        $(".chapter-button").html('<b>' + curChapter + '</b>');
        var chapters = "";
        for (var i = 1; i <= chapterList[curBook]; i++) {
            chapters = chapters + '<li><a class="nav-chapter-btn" data-value="' + i + '">' + i + '</a></li>';
        }
        $(".chapter-menu-fill").html(chapters);
        var height = $(window).height();
        $(".dropdown-menu").css("max-height", height - 85 + "px");
    });
    $(".body-text").load('../books/' + bookList[curBook] + '/' + curChapter + '.html', function() {
        applyOptions();
        $(".body-text").css("font-size", textSize + "px");
    });
}
```

With book-selection-dropdown.html looking like this (I cut out most of the book options so it would be more manageable):

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle book-button" data-toggle="dropdown"></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a class="nav-book-btn" data-value="1">Galatians</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-book-btn" data-value="2">Ephesians</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-book-btn" data-value="3">Philippians</a></li>
      <li class="disabled"><a>Colossians</a></li>
      <li class="disabled"><a>1 Thessalonians</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle chapter-button" data-toggle="dropdown"></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu chapter-menu-fill" role="menu">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And finally, I register selections with the following functions:

```
$(document).on('click', '.nav-book-btn', function() {
    curBook = $(this).data("value");
    curChapter = 1;
    loadText();
});
$(document).on('click', '.nav-chapter-btn', function() {
    curChapter = $(this).data("value");
    loadText();
});
```

So why would this work on desktops, and generate the lists correctly on mobile, but not allow the selecting of an option in the chapter list on mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this was the issue, but all it took to fix it was changing the css to set the cursor to pointer for the links in the chapter dropdown.

I noticed that the hover-over was not consistent between the two dropdowns and added the css to make them the same and now the navigation works across the board. If anybody knows why a style change affects the ability to click a link, I would love to hear, but this is what fixed it.